# taking the value of id from the iframe pathname with Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need to take the id from the url with java script (jquery). 
`$(document).find('iframe')[0].contentDocument.location.pathname` is giving such a result: `"/presentation/64/edit"`

I need to be able to check what is the id number in this url. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just split this string

```
var aa = "/presentation/64/edit";
aa.split("/");
aa[2];
```

**In full**

```
var Id=$(document).find("iframe")[0].contentDocument.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var frameId=$(document).find("iframe")[0].contentDocument.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var str = "/presentation/64/edit";
console.log(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));  // Result 64
```